# How to translate paths from C:\... to /c/... in vs-code tasks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, vscode-tasks

I would like to build my program using Git Bash or MinGW so I have this build task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": ["-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],          
            "options": {
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
                    "args": ["-l"]
                },
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
        },      
    ]
}
```

I have two issues:

1. The `cwd` command does not work because `${fileDirname}` is in the Windows form `C:\Foo\Bar` and since I am on `bash` I would like the POSIX form `/c/Foo/Bar`.
2. My task is not executed in the current terminal, but in a weird Window that display no output:

   ```
   /usr/bin/bash: gcc -g .vscode\tasks.json -o tasks: No such file or directory
   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

   Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) (v0.2.0) you can add Posix versions of the directory variables.

```
"cwd": "${command:extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirnamePosix}"
```